# Displaying dateDifference in two places

Tags: javascript

Please review this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/webfrogs/Stj5X/4/)

I have three date spans. The first date span works fine. It displays the number of days between the Start Date and the End Date.

This is the math used... This essentially shows the difference between A and B (B - A)

```
function dateDifference() {
    if($("#payPeriodEndDate").val()!='' && $("#payPeriodEndDate").val()!='') {

        var diff = ($("#payPeriodEndDate").datepicker("getDate") - $("#payPeriodStartDate").datepicker("getDate")) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24;
        $('#labelPayPeriodDays').html(diff+" Days in Pay Period");
    }
}
```

I've added another date field in there (Let's call it C)

This was added to show the difference between Dates C and A (C - A).

```
function dateDifference() {
    if($("#payPeriodEndDate").val()!='' && $("#payPeriodEndDate").val()!='') {

        var diff = ($("#payPeriodEndDate").datepicker("getDate") - $("#payPeriodStartDate").datepicker("getDate")) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24;
        $('#labelPayPeriodDays').html(diff+" Days in Pay Period");

function dateDifference() {
    if($("#lastDateOfAttendance").val()!='' && $("#lastDateOfAttendance").val()!='') {

        var diff = ($("#lastDateOfAttendance").datepicker("getDate") - $("#payPeriodStartDate").datepicker("getDate")) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24;
        $('#labelLastDateOfAttendance').html(diff+" Days of Attendance");
    }
}}}
```

Then it's supposed to display the number of days between C and A in a label.

It's not working, and I don't understand why. I've double-checked the math.

Thoughts?

**Update:**

I have an updated fiddle **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/webfrogs/Stj5X/5/)**.

I removed this snippet of code...

```
function dateDifference() {
    if($("#lastDateOfAttendance").val()!='' && $("#lastDateOfAttendance").val()!='') {
```

As well as two trailing '}' and now it spits out a huge milisecond amount and when I enter a date in the Last Date of Attendance field, it changes it from milisecs to a number in days.

Comment: You should always check your browser's developer console for errors. It'll save you a lot of trouble. You've dropped a spurious `function` declaration in the middle of the existing function. *edit* oh whoops it's not a syntax error :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this? http://jsfiddle.net/NYMTH/

```
function dateDifference() {
    if($("#payPeriodEndDate").val()!='' && $("#payPeriodEndDate").val()!='') {

        var diff = ($("#payPeriodEndDate").datepicker("getDate") - $("#payPeriodStartDate").datepicker("getDate")) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24;
        $('#labelPayPeriodDays').html(diff+" Days in Pay Period");
    }
}    
function dateDifference2() {
    if($("#lastDateOfAttendance").val()!='' && $("#lastDateOfAttendance").val()!='') {

        var diff = ($("#lastDateOfAttendance").datepicker("getDate") - $("#payPeriodStartDate").datepicker("getDate")) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24;
        $('#labelLastDateOfAttendance').html(diff+" Days of Attendance");
    }
}
```

I separated the date functions into two.

Comment: Ok. With my update above... I think I was on my way there, but you've done. Keep on coding my friend!